# presentModalViewControllver over a modalViewController works only once

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

For sake of simplicity I have 3 UIViewControllers named, vc0, vc1, vc2. My Flow of operations is a button in vc0 calls

```
[vc0 presentModalViewController:vc1]
```

Then in vc1 I have another button in vc1 that calls

```
[vc1 presentModalViewController:vc2]
```

In both vc1 and vc2 I have an X button that calls

```
[self dismissModalViewController];
```

Now the first run threw that flow is fine, vc1 is presented modally, followed by vc2 after the correct button presses. Dismissing the views also behaves correctly. However, when I attempt to start the flow all over again I'm unable to present vc2 modally from vc1. Has anyone else run into a similar problem before?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using "[self presentModalViewController:vc1]" vs "[vc0 presentModalViewController:vc1]"?

Comment: Correct, I nearly put in vc0 so everyone would understand which view controller that was being called in.

Comment: "I'm unable to present vc2 modally from vc1" -- show more code related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think You might be missing the allot + init for the view controllers that you want to present